# Set UITextField Keyboard With Created Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

in my application, I have created two targets: one is for the actual application and the other is for my custom keyboard. In my actual application, I have a `UITextField`, which the `keyboardType = .numberPad`. My issue now is that I am trying to set the `keyboardType` property of my `UITextField` with my custom keyboard. Anyway how I can do that?

Comment: I don't believe that you can force the use of a particular keyboard extension; the user needs to select that keyboard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do `myTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad`. That will make the keyboard a number pad for that specific `UITextField`.

Comment: That is what I have right now. My issue is that instead of `.numberPad`, I would like `myCustomKeyboard`

Comment: Is the `myCustomKeyboard` a `class`? If so, you could try `myTextField.keyboardType = myCustomKeyboard()`

Comment: This is not working as although `myCustomKeyboard` is a class, it exists in a different target.

Comment: What is the subclass of myCustomKeyboard?

Comment: It is `UIInputViewController`. I have trued creating it not as a different target but as part of my application and then setting the `textField.inputView` as `myCustomKeyboard`, but that did not work.

Comment: Did you try `textField.inputView = myCustomKeyboard()`?

Comment: Yes, I have posted the error I received in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
textField.inputView = myCustomKeyboard().inputView
```